# Finding the Big O complexity for ascending sorting code

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I need help to check whether my ascending sorting code has correct time complexity measurement or not.

Here is my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4344; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < 4344; j++)
    {
        if (array_dist[index_arr[i]] > array_dist[index_arr[j]])
        {
            x = index_arr[i];
            index_arr[i] = index_arr[j];
            index_arr[j] = x;
        }

    }
}
```

We have two nested loops so `N^2` and `if` statement with 3 operations, so `N^2 + 3` then we got `O(N^2)`.

I am not sure if `O(N^2)` is the correct time complexity for my code. I want to know if the `if` statement could change my answer?

Comment: Hint: can you construct an input where the `if` condition is always true?

Comment: Since the loops use constants it would be `O(1)` since the runtime isn't dependent on the length of the input (N). (It's always 4344)

Comment: "we have two nested loops so N^2" that's not always true, depends on flow control. But in your case yes, it is N^2, seems like bubble sort?

Comment: @Dúthomhas Does it matter?

Comment: @Quimby that is the right question. :O)

Comment: The `if` is irrelevant here since the content of the `if` block is `O(1)`. The number of time you execute the inner loop is `O(n^2)` (assuming you do not have constant bound), regardless of whether you enter the `if` or not. Entering the `if` or not (all the time) only multiply this `n^2` by a constant, so that's still `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @πάντα-ῥεῖ I don't think that duplicate is right. In the duplicate, in inner for-loop is inside the if and you can estimate the number of time you enter the if (and the complexity of `sqrt(n)` is not `O(1)`), that's very different from here, and the first/accepted answer does not apply here.

Comment: `N^2 + 3`: The way you get to this formula is incorrect. (Just add another loop with N iterations to the inner loop so according to your logic the complexity would be `O(N^2 + N) = O(N^2)` instead of `O(N^3)`.) The 3 statements are executed once per iteration of the inner loop and there are `N^2` of those. Furthermore assigning cost 1 to every single statement is pretty arbitrary and ignores the fact that there's a cost to evaluating the `if` condition; it's enough to argue that the loop body of the inner loop takes `O(1)` time...

Comment: @Holt so you are saying that my assumption is correct ?? So the time complexity of my code is 0(N^2) ???

Comment: @JOJO Yes, the time complexity is `O(N^2)`.

Comment: @JOJO However, this part *"We have two nested loops so N^2 and if statement with 3 operations, so N^2 + 3 [...]"*. You have `N^2 * 3` (times, not plus), because for every loop you execute 3 operations (assuming you always enter the `if`), but `O(3 * N^2)` is `O(N^2)`.

Comment: @Holt couls you please check this [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69754364/calculating-big-o-notation-that-has-three-nested-loops?noredirect=1#comment123298862_69754364)