# Calculating Big-O notation that has three nested loops

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I want to find Big_O notation for my code. It has three nested loops and each loop has parameter that maybe vary.
According to my understanding (I am not sure if that correct).

time complexity is `O(NKC)` where `N` is the size in the outer loop, `K` is a constant inserted by user. `C` is also constant that may be change when using other dataset.

my code:

```
 for (int m=0; m< size; m++)
    {
    int array_Y_class_target[2]{};
        float CT[2]{};
        float SumOf_Each_class_distances[2] = { 0.0 };
        int min_index = -1;
        for (int i = k; i > 0; --i) {
            for (int c = 0; c < 2; ++c) {
                for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
                       int index = index_arr[j];
                       if (Y_train[index] == c)
                    {
                        array_Y_class_target[c] ++;
                        float dist = array_dist[index_arr[j]];
                        SumOf_Each_class_distances[c] += dist;
                    }
                }
                if (array_Y_class_target[c] != 0)    
                {
    
                    CT[c] = (((float)k / (float)array_Y_class_target[c]) + (SumOf_Each_class_distances[c] / (float)array_Y_class_target[c]));
                }
                else
                {
                    CT[c] = 1.5; // max CT value
    
                }
                
            }
```

Comment: I'd say you're correct, but it's usually represented as O(N^3)

Comment: `O(k * k/2 * 2) -> O(k^2)`; although if C were 10000 it would still be O(k^2), because the constants are irrelevant.   You are looking for an expression of how the amount of work varies with the quantity of data.  Your quantity of data is K, and you have two nested loops based upon K.

Comment: Your code has four nested loops, not three. The outermost runs `size` times. The second runs `k` times (where `k` is not declared, so could be anything) if `k` is positive and will eventually overflow if `k` is negative (causing undefined behaviour). The third loop runs exactly twice.  The fourth (innermost) loop runs `i` times, where `i` is the index of the second loop.  Worst case complexity of the inner loop occurs if both  `if` conditions are true, and is a constant number of operations.  From that, the complexity is `O(size*k^2)` if `k` and `size` are nonegative, indeterminate otherwise.

Comment: @Peter But why `K^2` ??

Comment: @JOJO - there's a mathematical identity that sum of the values of `i` from `1` to `n` is `n*(n+1)/2`.     It is simple to prove that by induction (in fact, when I learned the principle of mathematical induction in secondary school, proving that was one of the first learning exercises).      In complexity theory it is also trivial to prove that `O(n^2  + n)` is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @Peter yes sure. Thank you Peter

Comment: @Peter: *"Your code has four nested loops, not three"*. Is the outer loop considered as nested ;-)